# What do these commands mean in laymans terms?

Tags: vpn

I am working on a project in packet tracer and Currently am creating a VPN for my WAN-RTR to PRIVATEWANRTR to BRANCH-2 from HQ. I have successfully created the VPN and memorized the commands. However even tho I am doing it I don't really understand what the commands mean. I was hoping someone on here with some experience could break down what each command actually means? I know it is a lot of work but it would be much appreciated.

CLI:

```
(config)#crypto isakmp policy 10
(config-isakmp)#encr aes
(config-isakmp)#authentication pre-share
HQ WAN Router Page 2
Step 7 Continued:
(config-isakmp)#group 2
(config-isakmp)#exit
(config)#crypto isakmp key yesterday123 address 50.50.50.50
b. Configure IPSec SA lifetime and Transform Set:
(config)#crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 86400
(config)#crypto ipsec transform-set BRANCH-2 esp-aes esp-sha-hmac Creates a
transform set called BRANCH-2 that will be used in the crypto map configuration
c. Create an Access Control List that matches any traffic going to Branch 2 networks:
This ACL will be used in the crypto map configuration
(config)#ip access-list extended BRANCH-2-TRAFFIC
(config-ext-nacl)#permit ip any 192.168.130.0 0.0.0.255
(config-ext-nacl)#permit ip any 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.255
(config-ext-nacl)#permit ip any 10.10.30.0 0.0.0.255
d. Create the crypto map that will be applied to the VPN-ONLY Internet ineterface:
(config)#crypto map BRANCH-2-MAP 100 ipsec-isakmp
(config-crypto-map)#set peer 50.50.50.50
(config-crypto-map)#set pfs group2
(config-crypto-map)#set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
(config-crypto-map)#set transform-set BRANCH-2
(config-crypto-map)#match address BRANCH-2-TRAFFIC
```

Comment: Before you can understand the commands, you need to understand how IPSec VPNs work and their associated terminology.  There are many web and video resources just a Google search away.